# Own markers on the axis of the plot

Tags: plotting, syntax

Could you please tell me how to make the ticks on the axes not in the numeric form (say, 0, 0.1, 0.2) but in symbolic form (say, "zero", "zero point one" and so on), in the plot command?

Comment: How would you like `0.325` be rendered?

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. : actually instead of numbers I want the symbolic quantities like $x_{0}, x_{1}$, so my question should be rephrased: I want to associate some of the numbers with corresponding symbols, say 0.325->$x_{0}$, and then to show these symbols on axis instead of the corresponding numbers. I am sorry for unclear formulations.

Comment: Like the $x$-axis on `With[{t = π Range[0, 3, 1/3]}, Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, Ticks -> {Transpose[{t, t}], Automatic}]]`?

Comment: @John Taylor Please have a look at the Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Ticks/Scope/TicksPositions and Labeling and there the last example shows exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I have not posted any answer for a very long time,

```
num = Range[5]
lab = Table[StringForm["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(``\)]\)", i], {i, num}]
tick = Transpose[{num, lab}]
Plot[x, {x, 1, 5}, Ticks -> {tick, Automatic}]
```

[image]